# what does livereload server do?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload

what does the `livereload` in grunt do, does `watch` already do what we want? For example if we run the server at port 9000 and the livereload server runs at port 9001. What will happen when there are changes in the files we are watching, should we see the newest content at `example.com:9001` or `example.com:9000`?

Comment: livereload has been deprecated in favour of [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload).

Comment: @Andy hmmm..so what does this livereload port number do? why we need it?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that you mentioned `watch` in your question. I'll try and reply below.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is I don't think you can do both. You can either have a simple node server running without livereload *or* livereload running *as part* of a node application. So, you can have your node server running on port 9000 *or* have livereload running as part of the node application on port 9001 (tho its default port is 35729).

I can only speak from my own experience on this. In my case I've used livereload when I am developing new code on my local development machine with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) - it's a built in feature of the webapp generator. Confusingly is that, while it defaults to port 35729, the generator implements [`connect-livereload`](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload), sets *its* port to 9000, and runs livereload through that, so that when run `grunt server` you open your application at port 9000 and livereload updates that port instead.

I would recommend reading the full documentation for `watch` particularly the [section about `connect-livereload`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-connect-middleware) is you want to know more.